# Laravel - How to pass a fixed value to controller from a fixed url on rout

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes

I want to pass an ID "0" to the controller if my url is user/new, how can i do it on the route.php in laravel?

I imagined something like this, but I don't think is that simple.

```
Route::get('user/new','UserController@edit', ['id'=>'0']);
Route::get('user/edit/{id}','UserController@edit');
```

With normal .htaccess i'd do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/new    /www/user/edit.php?id=0        [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)    /www/user/edit.php?id=$1      [L,QSA]
```

Do I need a middleware? Is there a more simple way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do once you receive id = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's semantically weird, creating an user with an `edit` function, anyways...

Why not use a php default paramenter value?

```
// UserController.php

public function edit($id = 0) // NOTICE THIS
{
  // your id is zero if none passed (when /new is called)
}
```

Your already existing `edit` wouldn't change and you don't have to touch your routes.

Comment: Worked fine, thank you a lot. I realy shouldn't name it Edit, i think I'll name it Manage. Tnks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a closure in your routes, like this:

```
Route::get('user/new', function() {
    return App::make('UserController')->edit(0);
});
```

But the Laravel way would be to use [RESTful resource controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers), which makes routes for create, edit and delete for you:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Comment: I realy liked the first way, but it didn't work. I got the error: 

"ReflectionException in Container.php line 736:
Class UserController does not exist"

I'm using Laravel 5, btw.

Comment: Your controller could be in some other namespace than usual. See this:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-have-problem-with-my-controller

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure why you want to do this, but you can do something like this in your controller:

```php
function newuser()
{
    return $this->edit(0);
}

function edit($id)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```